# Quicksort Algorithm crashes when sorting more than 36 elements

Tags: python, quicksort, infinite-recursion

So I thought for personal exercise I'd program a quicksort algorithm in Python 3.6. It's not that hard an algorithm and fairly easy to understand. To make matters a little more interesting I wanted to sort it **IN SITU** (without allocating as much space as the input). I realize it's not true in situ as I still allocate log(n) Memory but only because the variables don't get freed before calling the recursion.
Anyway I ran into a peculiar problem and that my algorithm sorts arrays up to 36 elements without fail and fast. But when I try to sort arrays with length 37 and more it just suddenly runs into an infinite recursion loop and crashes after 1000 recursions.

Can someone point me to the problem? I can't seem to find it.

```
randomnumbers = [160,51,77,32,53,44,83,116,128,170,190,192,192,117,28,32,9,17,136,146,47,67,20,196,41,122,17,13,11,176,198,79,166,71,114,44]#,116]#,167,200,159,50,76,71,198,157,116,124,83,149,37]
 #is the array one element shorter is suddenly works WTH?!

def quicksort (array, begin, final, o):
  pivotposition = 0

  if(final-begin==1):
    if(array[begin]>array[final]):
        #print("bla")
        temp = array[begin]
        array[begin] = array[final]
        array[final] = temp
    return
  elif(final-begin<1):
    return
  else:
    import random
    pivotposition = begin#random.randint(begin, final)

  pivot = array[pivotposition]
  start = begin
  end = final
  endfirst = 0
  print(o) #debugging print statement to check for the recursion depth
            #can be taken out without consequence
  while(start!=end):

    if(array[start]>pivot):
        if(pivotposition==end):
            pivotposition = start
        temp = array[start]
        array[start] = array[end]
        array[end] = temp
        end = end -1
    else:
        start = start + 1

  if(array[start]>pivot):
    endfirst=start-1
  else:
    endfirst=start

  lur = array[endfirst]
  array[endfirst] = array[pivotposition]
  array[pivotposition]= lur

  quicksort(array,begin,endfirst,o+1)
  quicksort(array,endfirst+1, final,o+1)

#-------------------------------------------------------
print(randomnumbers)
quicksort(randomnumbers, 0, len(randomnumbers)-1,0)
print(randomnumbers)

input("press Enter")
```

Comment: It may be helpful to determine whether there are any inputs that cause a crash, and which have fewer than 37 elements, as this will make debugging easier. For instance, I notice that `randomnumbers = [1,0,1]` will also cause a RecursionError.

Comment: Even though this is a "simple algorithm", you might want to comment your code so that someone reading your code just **know** what you intend to do, instead of him trying to know what you're doing.